# Cucumber with capybara step definition for checking existence of certain class in body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I need to define a step definition to check for the existence of a certain class in a body tag of a web page.

eg `<body class="home">`

I want to test if "home" is a class of body.

Bear in mind that body may contain other classes as well

eg `<body class="active home etc">`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would work if you test xpath (I'm not quite sure, then I don't put it as an answer :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find(:xpath, "//body")[:class]
```

will get you the string value of the class attribute.

I can edit if you need help with the regex to match, let me know-- don't forget about the case where the class you're trying to match is a substring of another class (ex: class="home_star_runner")

Comment: Thanks @carolclarinet, I can take it from here.